# Querying data from a table are missing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$items = '';
$sql = "select items from bplus where pos = 'home-01' limit 1";
$st = $db->query($sql);
$res = $st->fetchColumn();
$arr = explode("\n", $res);
foreach ($arr as $el){
//echo $el . "<br>"; // as a test - it's ok - four images.      
$sqlb = "select * from banners where fname = '" . $el . "'";
    $stb = $db->query($sqlb);
    $row = $stb->fetch();
    $items .= "<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/" . $el . "' alt='img' data-id = " . $row['id'] . " data-fname = '" . $row['fname'] . "' data-w = " . $row['width'] . " data-h = " . $row['height'] . ">\n"; 
}
echo $items;
```

Final result:

```
<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/5ad461206f52e.jpg
' alt='img' data-id =  data-fname = '' data-w =  data-h = >
<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/5ad461206f916.jpg
' alt='img' data-id =  data-fname = '' data-w =  data-h = >
<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/5ad461206fcff.jpg
' alt='img' data-id =  data-fname = '' data-w =  data-h = >
<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/5ad461207d7c2.jpg' alt='img' data-id = 29 data-fname = '5ad461207d7c2.jpg' data-w = 320 data-h = 50>
```

Why are the first three images without any data?

In the table all images has its data.

Comment: without knowing what's in the database, it's just guessing, I would wager that `$arr` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Also if you are going to use double quotes in `$items .= "<img` then you don't need the `.` dots. for example `"<img class='itemtop' src='../banners/{$el}' alt='img' ...."`  That said I dislike the single quotes in html attributes, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, pls see my line 7 - echo test

Comment: What is `$row['id']` this variable `$row` is not set in the code you posted.  I don't know what these `data-` attributes are for but they are likely just empty strings, and you have a PHP warning.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yest, it is set.

Comment: May be your `$el` contain spaces which cause the issue

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `$row = $stb->fetch();` - an array fatching columns values from `banners` table

Comment: That doesn't mean it's set that just means your querying for it, if there is a problem in your data there are no checks for false returns from the Database.  Are the images displayed with javascript?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, it cannot be the same because of `el` selector is different. Also checked

Comment: @puerto this seems to be an issue with the data, not with the code. The first three images are not found in the other table. You have to look for whitespaces. Also, your table design is incorrect, you should not store a delimited list of values in a single field value. You should create a separate table for them.

Comment: Try this query: `$sqlb = "select * from banners where fname = '" . trim($el) . "'";`

Comment: I'd suggest doing a var_export() of $el instead of just echoing. I'd wager a dollar your line breaks are windows style (\r\n).

Comment: @B.Desai, damn, you're right. trimming `el` works. thanks a lot.

Comment: @jpheldson, yes, you're right, trimming `el` solves all. thanks.

Comment: @shadow, thanks I see, I must create another database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `$el` variable contains spaces which cause the issue. So trim this data then get data from db

```
$sqlb = "select * from banners where fname = '" . trim($el) . "'";
    $stb = $db->query($sqlb);
    $row = $stb->fetch();
    $items .= "<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/" . $el . "' alt='img' data-id = " . $row['id'] . " data-fname = '" . $row['fname'] . "' data-w = " . $row['width'] . " data-h = " . $row['height'] . ">\n"; 
}
echo $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the results of your inner query

```
$sqlb = "select * from banners where fname = '" . $el . "'";
$stb = $db->query($sqlb);
$row = $stb->fetch();

if(!$row) throw new Exception("missing row [$el]");

$items .= "<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/" . $el . "' alt='img' data-id = " . $row['id'] . " data-fname = '" . $row['fname'] . "' data-w = " . $row['width'] . " data-h = " . $row['height'] . ">\n";
```

For the items I would add this (outside the loop)

```
$createData = function($k, $v){
    return 'data-'.$k.'="'.$v.'"';
};
```

Then in the loop after checking row

```
if(!$row) throw new Exception("missing row $el");

$data = implode(' ',array_map($createData, array_keys($row), $row)); 

$items .= '<img class="itemtop" src="../banners/'.$el.'" alt="img" '.$data.' >'.PHP_EOL;
```

This way it dynamically creates the `data-` based of what's in the query, then if you change "stuff" it is less code to maintain.

You can test it here

https://3v4l.org/Lo9Vf

One last thing is you can rename the columns in the query if they don't match, for example say in the DB the `w` is actually `width` then you can rename it like this

```
$sqlb = "select width AS w, first AS fname from banners ....;
```

And so on, I mention it because latter if you add a column to the `data` you only need to change the query and your all set, you don't have to change how the HTML is built, but that is up to you.  It's just how I would do it.

**UPDATE**

The bigger issue here is you Database model is not really correct, which gives rise to this issue an other complications.

Basically you have a many to relationship between the two tables and you are severely limiting what you can do by not molding the data correctly.  Currently you have

```
//table bplus 
items
1,2,3,4

//table banners
 fname
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Don't worry about the numbers the actual data in there is pretty much irrelevant.

What you need is something like this

```
//table bplus 
 //other fields

//table banners
fname bplus_id
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
```

Honestly I would need more information about the database to really help more.  But I suggest looking into Many to One relationships.  As you can eliminate continuously calling the DB inside the loop, which can get expensive, and probably simplify a lot of things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved by trimming `el`.

Comment: I would still have it check if `$row` is ok, I think using a Comma sperated column for the id's is probably the wrong way to do this.